# Ubuntu 14.04 black screen after switch GPU to nvidia at nvidia-prime

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, nvidia-prime

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 , desktop manager is lightdm, kernel is 3.13, after I installed the nvidia driver( I tried 331, 340, 343, all have this issue) from 'addtional driver' application and reboot, the screen freeze after login.
If I switch the gpu from nvidia to intel at 'nvidia x server settings'  before I reboot the PC, it's OK to login and everything is fine.

Any one has same issue? How can I fix this problem?

I tried install compiz-config-settings-manager and enable the unity plugin, but still doesn't fix the problem.

After install the nvidia driver, if I use Intel GPU, everything is fine, but as soon as I switch to Nvidia GPU and reboot it shows black screen, if I try logout/login the screen freeze.

If I type: `lspci | grep -i vga` it shows:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

and

```
/usr/bin/nvidia-detector
```

shows

```
none
```

and

```
lspci | grep -i NV
```

shows:

```
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
```

and I found out there is no **/etx/X11/xorg.conf** file exist so I run `nvidia-xconfig` to create one and select nvidia GPU then reboot, but still no luck, then I run `prime-select intel` switch to intel GPU and startup, the **/etx/X11/xorg.conf** missing again

```
$ sudo prime-switch nvidia
rmmod: ERROR: Module nvidia is not currently loaded
```

I have report this bug on launchpad.net:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331/+bug/1362848
if this bug also effects you ,please go there and click "This bug effects me" on top of the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a relatively old post, I'm not sure if the problem still exists, but I still will provide a possible solution.
It seems you have both graphics adapters from nvidia and intel, which is called nvidia optimus.
So you might want to look at the package bumblebee, which was written for this.
 `sudo apt-get install bumblebee` 
(type the above in a terminal, shortkey ctrl-alt-t)
To use it, you have to provide `optirun` in front of the executable program (for instance in front of the executable in a terminal) to be able to use the graphic power of the nvidia card. Else, the intel igp will be used.